# Drupal - Promote 50 nodes to front page when cron run

Tags: drupal, workflow

I have many nodes not yet promoted to front page. I want 50 nodes automatically promoted to front page for every cron run

I've tried many modules to doing this (using Rules:both stable release and dev, using core Action with Trigger, as well as using Triggerunlock)

None of them works

Answer (score 2):

If you know some PHP, you can write your own module:

1. Think of a name for your module (e.g. foo)
2. Create a file called *foo.module*
3. In that file, write a function `foo_cron`. This function will get executed each time cron runs (see [hook_cron](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer--hooks--core.php/function/hook_cron/6)).
4. [Tell drupal about your module](http://drupal.org/node/206756)

The function `foo_cron` might look like this:

```
function foo_cron() {
  // TODO: add appropriate WHERE clause and LIMIT clause  
  db_query('UPDATE {node} SET promote = 1');
  // TODO: maybe demote other nodes
}
```